# How to correctly copy the formatting of a shape in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an Excel spreadsheet with various shapes. The shapes change according to the status of each piece. I have a VBA Macro that runs a search for the status of each piece and changes the colors accordingly. At the end of the macro, I give a command for one of the pieces to copy the same formatting as another.

However, the formatting copied to this piece is the same as the formatting prior to the piece to be copied. For example, piece A is red. When running the macro, it becomes yellow. At the end of the code, I ask it to copy the formatting from piece A to piece B. Piece B, instead of becoming yellow, becomes red, meaning the previous status of the piece is always copied. Even if i create another Sub and run the code to copy the formatting, same thing happens, it copies the older formatting. Is there any Excel memory allocation characteristic that I am unaware of in this case?

Code used to copy the formatting

```
Set shapeOrigem = ws.Shapes("30090")
Set shapeDestino = ws.Shapes("30090b")
shapeDestino.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = shapeOrigem.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the color, then save the color as a `long` variable and apply it to the last shape. It should work and would be easy to maintain and follow.
Something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim preferredColor As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shapeOrigem As Shape, shapeDestino As Shape
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set shapeOrigem = ws.Shapes("30090")
    preferredColor = shapeOrigem.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
    'a lot of other code
    Set shapeDestino = ws.Shapes("30090b")
    shapeDestino.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = preferredColor

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried but had the same result. the strange thing is that If I actively change the shape's color by clicking with the mouse and altering the color, when I run the code, it copies the current color. However, if I do the same by running the code, it copies the previous color. And it's not a problem with the code order because I only execute the copy after all the shapes have been formatted.

That's why i thought it would mb something related to memory allocation of these data that i dont understand.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in your question, that replicates the issue? That can be copied and pasted into VBA?